# Getting Facebook Profile Name and Picture IOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-requests

I am having trouble getting facebook name and picture at the same time. I can take only one of them each request.

```
-(void)fbDidLogin{
    // Save the access token key info.
    [self saveAccessTokenKeyInfo];

    // Get the user's info.
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/?fields=first_name,picture" andDelegate:self];

}

-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];

        if ([result objectForKey:@"first_name"]) {
            [lblUser setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!", [result objectForKey:@"first_name"]]];
            // Show the publish button.
            [btnPublish setHidden:NO];
        }
    }
    else {
       imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
    }      
}
```

The errors I get

```
__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

If i approach with two requests

```
-(void)fbDidLogin{
    // Save the access token key info.
    [self saveAccessTokenKeyInfo];

    // Get the user's info.
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
```

and with the same -(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
the error i get is

```
[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

so how can i request to get facebook name and picture and how can handle incoming data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, following code works fine to get facebook name and profile picture

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
    // With this method we’ll get any Facebook response in the form of an array.
    // In this example the method will be used twice. Once to get the user’s name to
    // when showing the welcome message and next to get the ID of the published post.
    // Inside the result array there the data is stored as a NSDictionary.    


    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Profile Picture");
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
        //[profilePicture release];
        //profilePicture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: result];
    }


  if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        // The first object in the result is the data dictionary.

        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];


    }

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        // If the current result contains the "first_name" key then it's the user's data that have been returned.
        // Change the lblUser label's text.
        [lblUser setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!", [result objectForKey:@"first_name"]]];
        // Show the publish button.
        [btnPublish setHidden:NO];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response that the Facebook server gives you is one dictionary, not an array. Remove the two lines concerning `NSArray` and simply use:

```
if ([result objectForKey:@"first_name"]) {
        [lblUser setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!", [result objectForKey:@"first_name"]]];
        NSLog(@"%@", lblUser);
        // Show the publish button.
        [btnPublish setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: i dont think response of facebook is dictionary i just changed to this and its works if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]